# Access / record step size in python scipy's `solve_ivp` ODE solver

Tags: python, scipy, ode

The question is pretty much in the title: I would like to trace / record / access the step size that is used (and possibly changed dynamically) by `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`.

It does not seem to be returned in the result object.

Is there anyway to do that (if possible without altering too much the integration time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the output steps, that is, leave the default `t_eval=None`. Then the fields `.t` and `.y` of the output contain the times and state values of the internal steps.

Comment: I was somehow convinced the default choice of `t_eval` was built up on a much more complicated procedure. I just checked the source code, and it is as you say.